# How do I code a pop up dialog box to appear when the user clicks the X button to exit the program?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am building a UI using eclipse, java, and Scenebuilder. I need a Save before exiting pop up dialog box to appear when the user clicks the X button to exit the program. So far, I built a close button in scenebuilder and when pressed the pop up dialog box appears but not when I click the X button. 
Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
{
    ...
}

// Save Dialog
public void confirmDialogBox() {

    System.out.println("Hello");
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Save Dialog Box");
    alert.setHeaderText("Do you wish to save changes before exiting?");
    alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");
    ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Yes");
    ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);


    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            // Wait for 5 secs
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            if (alert.isShowing()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> alert.close());
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
    alert.showAndWait();
    System.out.println("Bye");


}


@Override
public void stop()
{
    System.out.println("Stage is closing");
    // Save file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so pretty simply by interrupting the normal JavaFX life cycle. We can catch any requests to close the window and run our own process to either allow or deny the request.

I've included a simple application (with comments) that demonstrates the concept:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Button to close the window/application
        Button btnExit = new Button("Exit");
        btnExit.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (confirmExit()) {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });

        // Now, add a custom handler on the Window event so we can handle the requast ourselves
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                // Run the confirmExit() method and consume the event if the user clicks NO, otherwise Exit
                if (confirmExit()) {
                    primaryStage.close();
                } else {
                    // Consume the event. This prevents the window from closing and the application exiting.
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(btnExit);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean confirmExit() {

        // Get confirmation that you want to exit
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Exit?");
        alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(
                ButtonType.YES,
                ButtonType.NO
        );

        // Get the result of the Alert (which button was selected
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        // Return true if the user clicked YES, false if they click NO or close the alert.
        return result.orElse(ButtonType.NO) == ButtonType.YES;
    }
}
```

---

With this method, the `handleExit()` method is called whether the user clicks the button or closes the window. You can do your work to save files in that method.

Comment: Thank you, @fabian. I updated my code sample with your suggestions. Much cleaner.